# Using send_dbmail to send emails from a email table

Tags: sp-send-dbmail

I'm new creating Sprocs and using `send_dbmail`.  But i was able to get `send_dbmail` to send an email when using a trigger.  However i have read in many spots that thats not a good practice.  So I have a trigger update an `Email_Tracker_Log` table when we want emails sent out.  Then i need to have a SQL Job that will run a SProc to query that table and send out the emails.  Once the email has been sent i then want that Sproc to update the table to show it has been sent.

Table Setup

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Email_Tracker_Log](
    [Email_Log_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email_Log_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Email_Sent] [bit] NULL,
    [Email_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SS_Username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SS_First_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SS_Last_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SS_Employ_ID] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I need some help to write my sproc to loop though this table and call `Exec sp_send_dbmail` for each row in the table.

Then once its been sent it needs to update the `[Email_Sent]` field with a `1` or `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code

```
   SELECT * FROM [YourTable]
   While records
   begin
     Compose email;
     send email;
   end;
```